# SVG icon change inside fill color

Tags: css, svg

I have this facebook SVG icon, that I need to be able to change the circle color and the inside  color (icon itself). How do I change it from transparent to white?

what I have
[image: what I have]
what I need
[image: what I need]

SVG code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<div id="facebook">
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="49.652px" height="49.652px" viewBox="0 0 49.652 49.652" style="enable-background:new 0 0 49.652 49.652;"
     xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <g>
        <path d="M24.826,0C11.137,0,0,11.137,0,24.826c0,13.688,11.137,24.826,24.826,24.826c13.688,0,24.826-11.138,24.826-24.826
            C49.652,11.137,38.516,0,24.826,0z M31,25.7h-4.039c0,6.453,0,14.396,0,14.396h-5.985c0,0,0-7.866,0-14.396h-2.845v-5.088h2.845
            v-3.291c0-2.357,1.12-6.04,6.04-6.04l4.435,0.017v4.939c0,0-2.695,0-3.219,0c-0.524,0-1.269,0.262-1.269,1.386v2.99h4.56L31,25.7z
            "/>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You saved my lot of effort. I was not quite sure about how to ask Google the question! :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the `<path>` in the SVG is just defining the shape of the black part of your icon.

If you want to make the "f" white, there are two options.

1. add a white shape behind the path so that it shows through the hole.

```css
div {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="facebook">
<svg id="Capa_1"
     width="49.652px" height="49.652px" viewBox="0 0 49.652 49.652">
  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="white"/>
  <path d="M24.826,0C11.137,0,0,11.137,0,24.826c0,13.688,11.137,24.826,24.826,24.826c13.688,0,24.826-11.138,24.826-24.826
            C49.652,11.137,38.516,0,24.826,0z M31,25.7h-4.039c0,6.453,0,14.396,0,14.396h-5.985c0,0,0-7.866,0-14.396h-2.845v-5.088h2.845
            v-3.291c0-2.357,1.12-6.04,6.04-6.04l4.435,0.017v4.939c0,0-2.695,0-3.219,0c-0.524,0-1.269,0.262-1.269,1.386v2.99h4.56L31,25.7z"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

2. Split the path into its two parts: the outside circle, and the "f" shape. Make the "f" shape white.

```css
div {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="facebook">
<svg id="Capa_1"
     width="49.652px" height="49.652px" viewBox="0 0 49.652 49.652">
  <path d="M24.826,0C11.137,0,0,11.137,0,24.826c0,13.688,11.137,24.826,24.826,24.826c13.688,0,24.826-11.138,24.826-24.826 C49.652,11.137,38.516,0,24.826,0z"/>
  <path d="M31,25.7h-4.039c0,6.453,0,14.396,0,14.396h-5.985c0,0,0-7.866,0-14.396h-2.845v-5.088h2.845 v-3.291c0-2.357,1.12-6.04,6.04-6.04l4.435,0.017v4.939c0,0-2.695,0-3.219,0c-0.524,0-1.269,0.262-1.269,1.386v2.99h4.56L31,25.7z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Pick which one you prefer.

Comment: HA! We had almost the same answer, you're 60 seconds faster :)

Comment: I prefer to use the first approach as it is cleaner and easier to understand specially someone like me :) Thanks a lot! It worked nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't change the color of the `f` in the logo, as the black is all one shape, so it's actually cut out from the circle. What you can do, is add another shape that sits behind the logo in your SVG.

I cut down the SVG code you have:

**SVG:**

```
<div id="facebook">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="49.652px" height="49.652px" viewBox="0 0 49.652 49.652" style="enable-background:new 0 0 49.652 49.652;" xml:space="preserve">
  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" class="circle"/>
        <path d="M24.826,0C11.137,0,0,11.137,0,24.826c0,13.688,11.137,24.826,24.826,24.826c13.688,0,24.826-11.138,24.826-24.826
            C49.652,11.137,38.516,0,24.826,0z M31,25.7h-4.039c0,6.453,0,14.396,0,14.396h-5.985c0,0,0-7.866,0-14.396h-2.845v-5.088h2.845
            v-3.291c0-2.357,1.12-6.04,6.04-6.04l4.435,0.017v4.939c0,0-2.695,0-3.219,0c-0.524,0-1.269,0.262-1.269,1.386v2.99h4.56L31,25.7z
            " />


  </svg>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#facebook {
  background-color: red;
}

.circle {
  fill: white;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/gvpeLn91/

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious is of course to edit the SVG, another option would be to add a pseudo element matching the black circle.

This trick could be handy if one for example loads icons from a CDN or similar, where it is not possible to edit the SVG.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

div svg {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="facebook">
  <svg id="Capa_1" width="49.652px" height="49.652px" viewBox="0 0 49.652 49.652">
  <path d="M24.826,0C11.137,0,0,11.137,0,24.826c0,13.688,11.137,24.826,24.826,24.826c13.688,0,24.826-11.138,24.826-24.826
            C49.652,11.137,38.516,0,24.826,0z M31,25.7h-4.039c0,6.453,0,14.396,0,14.396h-5.985c0,0,0-7.866,0-14.396h-2.845v-5.088h2.845
            v-3.291c0-2.357,1.12-6.04,6.04-6.04l4.435,0.017v4.939c0,0-2.695,0-3.219,0c-0.524,0-1.269,0.262-1.269,1.386v2.99h4.56L31,25.7z"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way I found so far is to use the CSS `clip-path` property. It works with any transparent image.

```css
img {
  background: #ff1234;
  clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/8/8730.png" width="150" height="150" />
```

More info about clipping and masking at https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/.